# JavaScript ul show and change color

Tags: javascript, html-lists

this is my first question here, so please be not too harsh ;)

I want to pop up a new listelement with javascript an also change the color of the link. How can i do that?

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(control, control2){
var elem = document.getElementById(control);
if(elem.style.display == "none"){
    elem.style.display = "block";
}else{
    elem.style.display = "none";
}

var elem = document.getElementById(control2);
if(elem.style.display == "rgb(0,10,50)"){
    elem.style.display = "rgb(50,10,60)";
}else{
    elem.style.display = "rgb(0,10,50)";
}
}
</script>

<li id="lifi" class="leistungen"><a href="javascript:toggle('first','lifi')"> x Zum aufklappen hier klicken.</a>
<ul id="first" style="display:none">
```

If I just do the first part, it works just fine. But with both parameters I cant get it to work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the second parameter, 'control2' to a different name than the first one, you cant use 'elem' for both:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggle(control, control2){
    var elem = document.getElementById(control);
    if(elem.style.display == "none"){
      elem.style.display = "block";
    }else{
      elem.style.display = "none";
  }

    var elem2 = document.getElementById(control2);
    if(elem2.style.display == "rgb(0,10,50)"){
    elem2.style.display = "rgb(50,10,60)";
   }else{
    elem2.style.display = "rgb(0,10,50)";
  }
 }
</script>
```

and welcome to stack overflow!